# Instant update on AppStore (websites like MobileRoadie and AppMakr)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, app-store

How do websites that allow user to make iPhone apps like MobileRoadie and AppMakr make immediate changes to the layout/font/color/style of your app even if your app is in AppStore? Don't they have to resubmit to the AppStore and wait like a week? Or they have some sort of contract with Apple?
Thanks.

Comment: MobileRoadie kind of looks like a terrible deal, moneywise, and AppMakr just looks like it makes highly specific RSS readers. I'm not sure how updating through the AppStore works, but once your app is established, I can't imagine updates would be subjected to separate submission procedures beyond a bit of testing for bad code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be achieve using some sort of websevices. Suppose each images comes from web services and when you run the app through web services images downloaded into device and stored into device.